# How do I use Sessions in PHP from command line?

Tags: c#, php, .net

I build a program which should have a `WebServer` included.

I used C# .Net Framework `HttpListener` to accept web requests. This works really well and I can easily deliver webpages with that.

Now, I thought of using PHP as well so I downloaded the executable and integrated them like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo
                    {
                        CreateNoWindow = true,
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        FileName = dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/php-7.1.11-Win32-VC14-x64/php.exe",
                        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
                        Arguments = "-e -f " + WorkingDir + parts[0] + " " + arguments,
                        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                        WorkingDirectory = WorkingDir
                    };
```

Where `parts[0]` is the PHP file.

I then read the output and send this back to the Browser. This work really great so far. But I have a problem using `Sessions` or `Cookies`.

If I call a PHP file with the following content:

```
<?php session_start();

include_once("plugins/Plugins.php");

if(isset($_SESSION["Plugins"]) == false) $_SESSION["Plugins"] = new Plugins();

var_dump($_SESSION["Plugins"]);
?>
```

I get 2 errors:

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent in *path* on line 1
>
> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers
>   already sent in
>   *path* on
>   line 1

Everything seems to be correct. I think it is the way I execute PHP.

Have someone done this yet? Any clues?

**Edit:**

I updated the code snippet. The Errors are gone but the Browser wont set any cookies or a session anyway.

Comment: For command-line scripts there is not really a concept of sessions because sessions are typically stored as cookies which can only be created via browser.

Comment: Yeah, I got that but the docu says the session_start command creates the headers wich are sent to the browser. Shouldnt this headers are included in the response of php.exe? How does something like xamp handle this? 
A 'normal' webserver is nothing more than a program, taking requests and put them into the php prozessor. In my opinion I should be able to recreate this behaviour.

Comment: It's nice to have opinions, but it doesn't make something fact. You could always write a PHP parser that handles sessions from the command line properly. Browsers all have the ability to handle headers and cookies, hence sessions. Command-line interactions are intended to be "stateless" and why no concept for sessions was cooked into PHP CLI.